# angular2 how to view template variable found in child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent and child component. Child component has template variables  and i want to read them into parent.

Parent:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {ChildComponent} from '/components/child/child.component'

@Component({
 selector: "parent",
 template: "<child [List]="List"></child>",
 directives: [ChildComponent]
})

 export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

 // list contains selectable items (<a> tag in HTML)
 @ViewChildren("item")
 itemsList: QueryList<ElementRef>;
}
```

child :

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
selector: "child",
templateUrl: "components/child/child.html",
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() list: array;
    .....
}
```

the template :  child.html

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of list" style="cursor: default;">
    <a (click)="handleClick()" #item > item </a>
 </li>
```

It is possible to obtain the items list in parent ??

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data to and from nested component.

If you want to pass data from child to parent, you can use event emitter.

Please see this article [Passing data to and from a nested component in Angular 2](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/)